# Can I use Lucene.net to index and join results from multiple sources

Tags: lucene.net

I want to use Lucene.net to index data from various sources (e.g. the local file system and a database). However, I'd like to link data from the two sources (based on a common field, such as an ID) and display the combined information to the user. As far as I can tell, I have three options. After indexing each source:

1. Use Lucene.net to combine the indexes in a search query into a single result set
2. Create some custom code to correlate results retrospectively; or
3. Store separate result sets in a database (in my case, it won't be the same database as the source). Then create a new index based on a query that joins the data

Option 1 is what I'd like to do, but I'm not sure how viable this is with Lucene for a couple of reasons:

- Lucene isn't a relational database, is this attempting something that Lucene is not really designed to do?
- Can combining indexes result in a noticeable performance hit?

The only reason I'd go for Option 2 is if I believe I can create an algorithm that is more efficient than Option 1. Following that line of logic, I then have to question if I should be using Lucene at all to correlate the data.

Which leads me onto Option 3. I'm happy that it will work, but it seems like a compromise:

- Data will be stored in a database as well as Lucene (as well as the original source)
- By introducing an extra step, it'll take longer to complete the process. I'm not sure how this will affect the user experience

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can, but you need to stop thinking relationally and start thinking in terms of documents rather than rows. Or, option 3 is the right approach. What you want to do is to create a single document holding:

a) whatever I wanted to search on -- analyized fields in lucene terms
b) pointers to the full, extant records -- basically the ID number or file location
c) if possible, enough stuff to show search results without having to reach out to the file system or the database -- stored fields in lucene parlance.

In terms of performance, there won't be too much overhead or overload. Adding things to indexes on the fly is not that big a performance hit, and lucene itself is astoundingly fast. I would build it in a rational, componentized manner then dive into performance if required.